# Worpdress selectbox to choose which and how many Posts to be displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a `custom-post-type` and now I would like to have a selectbox, where I can choose how many and which Posts I want to display on a specific page, for example the frontpage. How can I achieve that?

Any clue is useful

Comment: are you using ACF?

Comment: @charankumar yes I do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ACF plugin then you can use Relationship field to show selected post on pages. Here is the link

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/